# Silverlight: connecting to secured ASMX service

Tags: security, silverlight-4.0, https, asmx, credentials

I need to connect to an ASMX secured web service over HTTPS using Silverlight 4. I have been able to connect to the service using a WPF application using the following configuration:

```
  <binding name="wsSomeWebService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"
          realm="www.somedomain.com" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
  </binding>
```

And in code I do the following:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

However, when I try to connect from Silverlight I always get a security exception.

On the server the policy file looks like this:

```
<access-policy> 
  <cross-domain-access> 
    <policy> 
      <allow-from http-methods="*" http-request-headers="*">      
        <domain uri="*"/> 
      </allow-from>      
      <grant-to>      
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/> 
      </grant-to>      
    </policy> 
  </cross-domain-access> 
</access-policy>
```

On Silverlight, I have tried using this:

```
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="secureBinaryHttpBinding" >
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"/>
      <httpsTransport  />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

And also this:

```
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicSecureBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

But neither seems to work.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can reproduce the successful configuration I used in WPF on a Silverlight client?

Comment: What happens when you simply do an `Add Service Reference`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<domain uri="*"/>
```

use

```
<domain uri="http://*"/>
<domain uri="https://*" />
```

in your **clientaccesspolicy.xml**. Check this [link](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/14/calling-secure-services-with-silverlight-2-ssl-https.aspx) for details.

Comment: This change fixed the issue using the default basicHttpBinding. Thanks for that.